# A Toeplitz variant of the Hilbert matrix

Tags: reference-request, matrices, sp.spectral-theory

It is well-known that the Hilbert matrix $H$, i.e., the symmetric Hankel matrix with entries 
$$H_{m,n}=\frac{1}{m+n-1}, \quad m,n\in\mathbb{N},$$ 
determines a bounded operator on $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$. Moreover, it is known that $H$ is explicitly diagonalizable which is due to Rosenblum.

It seems to be very likely that also the Toeplitz analogue of the Hilbert matrix, i.e., the symmetric Toeplitz matrix $T$ with entries
$$T_{m,n}=\frac{1}{1+|m-n|},$$
is explicitly diagonalizable. Note that the matrix $T$ defines a densely defined (unbounded) operator on $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$.

Any information or reference concerning the spectral properties of $T$ would be appreciated.

Comment: On $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, an operator similar to $T$ is a convolution operator, therefore it is diagonalised by the Fourier transform. Therefore, I expect that the operator $T$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ will also have continuous spectrum. One might get an explicit expression for the (generalised) eigenvectors of $T$ through a Wiener–Hopf type factorisation. I worked on a similar continuous problem in $L^2((0, \infty))$, see [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/sm206-3-2). (The kernel $|x|^{-1}$ is not considered there, but it is essentially Example 6.1 there in the limiting case $\alpha \to 0^+$).